# Xubuntu. Shortcuts "Super" and "Super+key" run commands simultaneously

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

On Xubuntu I have shortcut-key <kbd>Super</kbd> for command "xfce4-appfinder".
So now I have difficulties when I use combinations with key <kbd>Super</kbd>.

For example when I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, two commands "xfce4-appfinder" and "xfce4-find-cursor" run at the same time.

It's not normal behavior. I guess it's only Xubuntu/xfce problem. Please help to fix it.

Comment: Wasn't Alt+F2 the original shortcut for `xfce4-appfinder`? Why did to change it to `Super`? You've seen the consequences.

Comment: Because it's faster to use one key than two. It doesn't matter what command is, I just want to use "Super" key for something, and I can't.

Comment: Yes, that's quite obvious and equally obvious is that you'll have two effects each time you use Super+anything. Change plain super to say, super+spacebar. If that's possible, I don't see how much longer that's going to take. And it's not like you're going to be using `xfce4-appfinder` that often to think in terms of saving significant amounts of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ksuperkey** solved my problem - https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey

Just follow instruction for compiling ksuperkey - https://store.kde.org/p/1081256/

> **Compiling from source**
>
> If there is no package for ksuperkey for your distribution, you can
>   compile the program from source following these instructions:
>
> 1. Install dependencies. On Ubuntu:
>
> `sudo apt-get install gcc make libx11-dev libxtst-dev pkg-config`
>
> On some system you'll also have to install the build-essential
>   package.
>
> 2. Download ksuperkey-0.4 (Source) from this page and extract the tar.gz file (using e.g. Ark).
> 3. Go to the newly extracted directory called ksuperkey, open a terminal (press F4 in Dolphin), and run:
>
> `make`
>
> 3b. Optionally, if you want to install ksuperkey to the standard PATH
>   for all users:
>
> `sudo make install`
>
> 4. Launch ksuperkey:
>
> `./ksuperkey`
>
> or by clicking on its icon. ksuperkey will run in the background. (If
>   you did step 3b, you can just type "ksuperkey" from anywhere to launch
>   it.)
>
> 5. Try to press the left Super key. If the application launcher does not show up, make sure that its shortcut is set to Alt+F1: right click
>      on the application launcher icon -> Application Launcher Settings ->
>      Keyboard Shortcut.

Then launch `ksuperkey -e 'Super_L=Alt_L|F3'` or add the command to autostart.

**Update**. Maybe it's better to use [**xcape**](https://github.com/alols/xcape) instead. Because it's original, from where ksuperkey was forked.

Installation and command is the same - `xcape -e 'Super_L=Alt_L|F3'`